# android camerax preview gets black after taking some photos

Tags: android-camerax, android-developer-api

I have developed an android app using camerax, most of the time it works fine however after taking several photos the camera preview gets black. When you close preview activity and return the same screen black again.
No error in log.
Could be a wrong memory handling?
This is my code, its extended because I have implemented zoom and rotation. Another idea is the unbindAll part

this line  *cameraProvider.unbindAll();* i don't understand where to call it

```
  private void startCamera(boolean enableTorch) {

        final ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider> cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this);

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                    ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get();
                  
            Preview preview = new Preview.Builder()
                    .setTargetAspectRatio(AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3)
               .build();

            cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder()
                    .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
                    .build();

            ImageAnalysis imageAnalysis = new ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                    .build();
            ImageCapture.Builder builder = new ImageCapture.Builder();
            final ImageCapture imageCapture = builder    .setTargetRotation(this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation())                 .setTargetAspectRatio(AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3)                   .setCaptureMode(CAPTURE_MODE_MAXIMIZE_QUALITY)
               preview.setSurfaceProvider(mPreviewView.createSurfaceProvider());
            cameraProvider.unbindAll();
            camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle((LifecycleOwner) this, cameraSelector, preview, imageAnalysis, imageCapture);
            camera.getCameraControl().enableTorch(enableTorch);
            CameraControl cameraControl = camera.getCameraControl();
            ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener listener = new ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

                    float currentZoomRatio = camera.getCameraInfo().getZoomState().getValue().getZoomRatio();
                    float delta = detector.getScaleFactor();
                     cameraControl.setZoomRatio(currentZoomRatio * delta);
                     return true;
                }
            };
            ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(this, listener);
            mPreviewView.setOnTouchListener((view, event) -> {
                scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        MeteringPoint point = mPreviewView.createMeteringPointFactory(cameraSelector).createPoint(event.getX(), event.getY());
                        FocusMeteringAction action = new FocusMeteringAction.Builder(point).build();

                        camera.getCameraControl().startFocusAndMetering(action);

                        return true;
                    default:
                        return false;
                }
            });

         

            OrientationEventListener orientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener((Context) this) {
                @Override
                public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
                    int rotation;

                    // Monitors orientation values to determine the target rotation value
                    if (orientation >= 45 && orientation < 135) {
                        rotation = Surface.ROTATION_270;
                    } else if (orientation >= 135 && orientation < 225) {
                        rotation = Surface.ROTATION_180;
                    } else if (orientation >= 225 && orientation < 315) {
                        rotation = Surface.ROTATION_90;
                    } else {
                        rotation = Surface.ROTATION_0;
                    }
                 
                    imageCapture.setTargetRotation(rotation);
                }
            };

            orientationEventListener.enable();

            captureImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    File file = new File(archivo_foto);
                 
                    ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions outputFileOptions = new ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(file).build();
                    imageCapture.takePicture(outputFileOptions, executor, new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onImageSaved(@NonNull ImageCapture.OutputFileResults outputFileResults) {
                          
                       
                            //veo la imagen
                            try {
                              
                                if (ComprasUtils.debeRotar(MiCamaraActivity.this)) {
                                    getRotacionConf(archivo_foto); //o sea no funcionará getrotacion2
                                } else
                                    getRotacion2(archivo_foto);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            vistaPrevia();

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(@NonNull ImageCaptureException error) {
                            error.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            btnflash.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (camera.getCameraInfo().hasFlashUnit()) {
                        cameraControl.enableTorch(camera.getCameraInfo().getTorchState().getValue() == TorchState.OFF);
                    }
                }
            });
            camera.getCameraInfo().getTorchState().observe(this, new Observer<Integer>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChanged(Integer integer) { //para cambiar imagen del boton
                            if (integer == TorchState.OFF) {
                                btnflash.setImageResource(R.drawable.flash_on);
                            } else {
                                btnflash.setImageResource(R.drawable.flash_off);
                            }
                        }
                    }
            );

                } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                   
                    // This should never be reached.
                }
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this));
            }

        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
           milog.grabarError(TAG+" "+ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: Hmm black preview is an interesting case. What is your CameraX version and device model? One thing you could try is setting your `PreviewView` to COMPATIBLE mode. You don't have to call unbindAll. The camera stack stops when the lifecycle stops.

Comment: @Xi 张熹 libraries i'm using:
 androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.0.0-beta05
 androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.0.0-beta05
androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha12
androidx.camera:camera-extensions:1.0.0-alpha12    device: Galaxy A22 5G

Comment: That's a pretty old version. Please at least upgrade it to 1.2.0 and try again.